# Calling Correct Method Based on Instance Type

Tags: c#, inheritance, overloading

I am writing a program in C#. I am trying to do something but it does not do what I expected.

I have an interface **I**, class **C1** and class **C2**.

**C1** implements interface **I**. **C2** inherits from **C1**.

Interface **I** has a method declaration called **equals** which is implemented in **C1**. In class **C2**, there is an **equals** method too which extends parent class (C1) **equals** method by checking additional things to decide equality. In class **C2**'s equal method, i used base keyword to call equals method in C1 and i used some additional variables to decide equality. You can think it like following, according to C1 equality depends on 3 variables and for C2 equality depends on 5 variables including variables in C1.

Up to this point there is no problem. However, in a method which accepts interface **I** as parameter, declared like following;

```
void myMethod(I param1)
```

when i pass **C2** instance, I want to use **equals** method in **C2** (extended one), when I pass **C1** instance I want to use equals method in **C1**. However, program every time uses **equals** method in **C1**, it never uses equals in **C2**. What I am doing wrong, how can I make program to use equals method in correct class.

Thanks

Comment: can you post simplified code for your classes and interface?

Answer (score 0):

C2 doesn't implement your equals method directly. If you want to use the C2 Equals method when you pass an instance of C2 as the interface, you need to Cast it to the type C2 and then you'll be able to use the C2 implementation of Equals.

```
//psudocode
void myMethod(I param1)
{
 var obj = param1 as C2;
  if(obj != null)
  //use obj.Equals method which will use the C2 implementation.
  if(obj == null)
  //this is a C1 type and will use C1 equals method via param1.Equals
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you marked method `equals` in class C1 with keyword virtual and `equals` in C2 with override? Only then the `equals` method will be overridden in C2 (otherwise it will be new method that have nothing in common with interface I or class C1).

```
public interface I
{
    bool equals(I other);
}

public class C1 : I
{
    public virtual bool equals(I other)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C1.equals");
        return false;
    }
}
public class C2 : C1
{
    public override bool equals(I other)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C2.equals");
        return false;
    }
}
```